# pthread deadlock issue when using pthread_cond_t

Tags: pthreads, deadlock

I am having horrible time trying to figure out why my sync. code gets deadlocked when using pthread library. Using winapi primitives is instead of pthread works with no problems. Using c++11 threading also works fine (unless compiled with visual studio 2012 service pack 3, there it just crashes - Microsoft accepted it as a bug.) Using pthread however proves to be a problem - at least running in on linux machine, haven't had a chance to try different OS.

I've written a simple program which illustrates the issue. The code is just showing the deadlock - I am well aware the design is pretty poor and can be written much better.

```
typedef struct _pthread_event
{
     pthread_mutex_t Mutex;
     pthread_cond_t Condition;
     unsigned char  State;
} pthread_event;

void pthread_event_create( pthread_event * ev , unsigned char init_state )
{ 
    pthread_mutex_init( &ev->Mutex , 0 );
    pthread_cond_init( &ev->Condition , 0 );
    ev->State = init_state;
}

void pthread_event_destroy( pthread_event * ev )
{
    pthread_cond_destroy( &ev->Condition );
    pthread_mutex_destroy( &ev->Mutex );
}

void pthread_event_set( pthread_event * ev , unsigned char state )
{
    pthread_mutex_lock( &ev->Mutex );
    ev->State = state;
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &ev->Mutex );
    pthread_cond_broadcast( &ev->Condition );
}

unsigned char pthread_event_get( pthread_event * ev )
{
    unsigned char result;
    pthread_mutex_lock( &ev->Mutex );
    result = ev->State;
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &ev->Mutex );
    return result;
}

unsigned char pthread_event_wait( pthread_event * ev , unsigned char state , unsigned int timeout_ms )
{
    struct timeval time_now;
    struct timespec timeout_time;
    unsigned char result;

    gettimeofday( &time_now , NULL );
    timeout_time.tv_sec = time_now.tv_sec           + ( timeout_ms / 1000 );
    timeout_time.tv_nsec = time_now.tv_usec * 1000  + ( ( timeout_ms % 1000 ) * 1000000 );

    pthread_mutex_lock( &ev->Mutex );
    while ( ev->State != state ) 
          if ( ETIMEDOUT == pthread_cond_timedwait( &ev->Condition , &ev->Mutex , &timeout_time ) ) break;

    result = ev->State;
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &ev->Mutex );
    return result;
}

static pthread_t        thread_1;
static pthread_t        thread_2;
static pthread_event    data_ready;
static pthread_event    data_needed;

void * thread_fx1( void * c )
{
    for ( ; ; )
    {
        pthread_event_wait( &data_needed , 1 , 90 );
        pthread_event_set( &data_needed , 0 );
        usleep( 100000 );
        pthread_event_set( &data_ready , 1 );
        printf( "t1: tick\n" );
    }
}

void * thread_fx2( void * c )
{
    for ( ; ; )
    {
        pthread_event_wait( &data_ready , 1 , 50 );
        pthread_event_set( &data_ready , 0 );
        pthread_event_set( &data_needed , 1 );
        usleep( 100000 );
        printf( "t2: tick\n" );
    }
}


int main( int argc , char * argv[] )
{
    pthread_event_create( &data_ready , 0 );
    pthread_event_create( &data_needed , 0 );

    pthread_create( &thread_1 , NULL , thread_fx1 , 0 );
    pthread_create( &thread_2 , NULL , thread_fx2 , 0 );

    pthread_join( thread_1 , NULL );
    pthread_join( thread_2 , NULL );

    pthread_event_destroy( &data_ready );
    pthread_event_destroy( &data_needed );

    return 0;
}
```

Basically two threads signaling each other - start doing something, and doing their own thing even if not signaled after a short timeout.

Any idea what it going wrong there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `timeout_time` parameter to `pthread_cond_timedwait()`. The way you increment it is eventually and quite soon going to have an invalid value there with nanosecond part bigger than or equal to billion. In this case `pthread_cond_timedwait()` perhaps return with `EINVAL`, and probably actually before waiting for the condition.

The problem can be found *very quickly* with `valgrind --tool=helgrind ./test_prog` (quite soon it said it had already detected 10000000 errors and gave up counting):

```
bash$ gcc -Werror  -Wall -g test.c -o test -lpthread && valgrind --tool=helgrind ./test
==3035== Helgrind, a thread error detector
==3035== Copyright (C) 2007-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by OpenWorks LLP et al.
==3035== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3035== Command: ./test
==3035== 
t1: tick
t2: tick
t2: tick
t1: tick
t2: tick
t1: tick
t1: tick
t2: tick
t1: tick
t2: tick
t1: tick
==3035== ---Thread-Announcement------------------------------------------
==3035== 
==3035== Thread #2 was created
==3035==    at 0x41843C8: clone (clone.S:110)
==3035== 
==3035== ----------------------------------------------------------------
==3035== 
==3035== Thread #2's call to pthread_cond_timedwait failed
==3035==    with error code 22 (EINVAL: Invalid argument)
==3035==    at 0x402DB03: pthread_cond_timedwait_WRK (hg_intercepts.c:784)
==3035==    by 0x8048910: pthread_event_wait (test.c:65)
==3035==    by 0x8048965: thread_fx1 (test.c:80)
==3035==    by 0x402E437: mythread_wrapper (hg_intercepts.c:219)
==3035==    by 0x407DD77: start_thread (pthread_create.c:311)
==3035==    by 0x41843DD: clone (clone.S:131)
==3035== 
t2: tick
==3035== 
==3035== More than 10000000 total errors detected.  I'm not reporting any more.
==3035== Final error counts will be inaccurate.  Go fix your program!
==3035== Rerun with --error-limit=no to disable this cutoff.  Note
==3035== that errors may occur in your program without prior warning from
==3035== Valgrind, because errors are no longer being displayed.
==3035== 
^C==3035== 
==3035== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3035== Use --history-level=approx or =none to gain increased speed, at
==3035== the cost of reduced accuracy of conflicting-access information
==3035== ERROR SUMMARY: 10000000 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 412 from 109)
Killed
```

There is also two other minor comments:

1. For improved correctness, in your `pthread_event_set()` you could have the condition variable broadcast be done before mutex unlock (the effect of wrong ordering basically could break the determinism of the scheduling; `helgrind` complains about this issue too);
2. you could safely drop the mutex locking in pthread_event_get() to return the value of `ev->State` - this should be atomic operation.

Comment: Wow, that was actually way easier to fix than I dreaded. Just added      timeout_time.tv_sec += timeout_time.tv_nsec / 1000000000;
timeout_time.tv_nsec = timeout_time.tv_nsec % 1000000000;
to normalize it and it's running fine. Thank you!